# Ionic 4 how to set button on bottom of page in slider?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am trying to show the button on the bottom of page but the issue is its not showing in bottom just showing on the middle not in end.

Here is my .html code

```
<ion-header no-border>
<ion-toolbar >
    <ion-buttons slot="start" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 5px;">
      <img src="assets/icon/favicon.png" height="50px">
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="skip()"><p>SKIP</p></ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div>
    <ion-slides pager="true" #mySlider>
      <!-- Slide 1 -->
      <ion-slide>
        <div>
            <img src="assets/welcome-slides/portrait.png"/>
            <h2>
              Capture the moment
            </h2>
            <ion-label color="gray">
              Our photographer will capture the shot in the right place.
            </ion-label>
        </div>

          <ion-button expand="block" class="btn" (click)="swipeNext()">NEXT</ion-button>
      </ion-slide>

    </ion-slides>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

.scss

```
.toolbar-background {
    border: none;
}


.btn{
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  position : absolute;
  bottom : 0;
  left: 5%;

}

ion-slide {
     padding-top: 0px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;
}


.bar-header {
    background-color: red($color: #000000);
    border: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

[image]

I try to set height of slide but dont know why its not working seems like button is in the end of slide but the height is less thats why button is showing in middle.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your button outside of the `<ion-slides>` component.

```
<ion-header no-border>
<ion-toolbar >
    <ion-buttons slot="start" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 5px;">
      <img src="assets/icon/favicon.png" height="50px">
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="skip()"><p>SKIP</p></ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div>
    <ion-slides pager="true" #mySlider>
      <!-- Slide 1 -->
      <ion-slide>
        <div>
            <img src="assets/welcome-slides/portrait.png"/>
            <h2>
              Capture the moment
            </h2>
            <ion-label color="gray">
              Our photographer will capture the shot in the right place.
            </ion-label>
        </div>
      </ion-slide>

    </ion-slides>
    <!-- put your button here -->
    <ion-button expand="block" class="btn" (click)="swipeNext()">NEXT</ion-button>
    <!-- put your button here -->
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Issue is i have seperste 3 buttons. On 1st and second slide i have next button and on 3rd i have get started buttin

Comment: Use `*ngIf` to show a specific button for a specific slide

Comment: Or better yet use the same button and just use a switch statement to handle the click logic for each slide